# orWhere to orWhereIn with Laravel syntax and raw queries

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

To get an SQL Statement like this;

```
SELECT postcode FROM Payment WHERE 
  countries IN ('E92000001', 'L93000001') AND 
  counties IN ('95', 'E10000002') AND 
  gors in ('A', 'B');
```

My code is currently;

```
$postcode_extract = PostcodeExtract::all();

foreach ($input as $column => $values) {
            $postcode_extract->whereIn($column, $values);
    }
```

I need to switch those ANDs to ORs. I *think* I might have it;

```
foreach ($input as $column => $values) {
    $postcode_extract->orWhere(function ($query) use ($column, $values) {
                                $query->whereIn($column, $values);
                                });
        }
```

I do get results.. It's hard to tell without seeing the raw query though. I used `toSql()` and this is the result;

```
select * from `201502_postcode` where (`country` in (?, ?)) or (`county` in (?, ?)) or (`gor` in (?, ?))
```

Why the `?`s though? Why not the real data or is that not how `toSql` works?

-- UPDATE --

Here is my code using `toSql`;

```
$sql = $postcode_extract->toSql();

print_r($sql);
```

I do it after the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses prepared statements so to get sql query and arguments you need to use not only `toSql()` method but also `getBindings()`, so to get full query you could use for example:

```
$sql = str_replace(['%', '?'], ['%%', "'%s'"], $postcode_extract->toSql());
$fullSql = vsprintf($sql, $postcode_extract->getBindings());
```